# Can I have my Makefile automatically make GCC use the most recent standard it supports?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, gnu-make

My C++03 project needs an upgrade to C++11, and I can guarantee that at least experimental support for it will be available in all the GCCs I want to use.

However, that may be `-std=c++0x` or it may be actual `-std=c++11` from newer GCC. One day it'll be `-std=c++14` (when CentOS catches up…).

**How can I form a GNU Makefile that adds the "best" flag to `CXXFLAGS` depending on which will succeed?**

I *could* just say "okay, my earliest GCC in use still doesn't have production-ready C++11 support so I should stick with C++03", but meh.

Comment: `-std=c++0x` works in newer versions, as a synonym for `-std=c++11`, so you can just use that

Comment: Respect for putting C++03 migration onto your devstream.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Took us long enough! Management buy-in was easy back when they thought it was just a case of flicking a switch lol

Comment: @JonathanWakely: ..... oh. Still, I'd like to be able to continue this trend when I have access to a C++14 compiler, so... I want my Makefile to compile against the most recent available supported language standard, then (I guess) use macros to make the code itself "portable". I've tweaked the wording slightly.

Comment: I'm wondering what you gain by this. Either your code needs `-std=c++14` or it doesn't. In the first case, older GCC versions are out; in the latter case you can just use `-std=c++11`. That said, GCC really needs a `-std=c++now` and have it as the default.

Comment: @MSalters The default was gnu++98 for a long time, now it is gnu++14, so I would say that it is already the case. There could be a -std=c++next that would always be experimental...

Comment: @MSalters: I'm already targeting "C++0x" and C++11 so even before bringing C++14 into the picture there is already a benefit. Granted, that may be where the true benefit ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will select the best option supported by the `$(CXX)` compiler:

```
CXX_MODE.42 := -std=c++98
CXX_MODE.43 := $(CXX_MODE.42)
CXX_MODE.44 := $(CXX_MODE.43)
CXX_MODE.45 := $(CXX_MODE.44)
CXX_MODE.46 := -std=c++0x
# Unnecessary, since -std=c++0x still works, but hey why not:
CXX_MODE.47 := -std=c++11
CXX_MODE.48 := $(CXX_MODE.47)
CXX_MODE.49 := $(CXX_MODE.48)
CXX_MODE.5 := -std=c++14
CXX_MODE.6 := $(CXX_MODE.5)
GXX_VERSION := $(shell $(CXX) -dumpversion | awk -F. '$$1<5{print $$1$$2} $$1>=5{print $$1}')
CXX_MODE := $(CXX_MODE.$(GXX_VERSION))
CXXFLAGS += $(CXX_MODE)
```

For extra fun you could choose between `c++` and `gnu++` modes based on some other variable:

```
CXX_MODE.42 := 98
CXX_MODE.43 := $(CXX_MODE.42)
CXX_MODE.44 := $(CXX_MODE.43)
CXX_MODE.45 := $(CXX_MODE.44)
CXX_MODE.46 := 0x
# Unnecessary, since -std=c++0x still works, but hey why not:
CXX_MODE.47 := 11
CXX_MODE.48 := $(CXX_MODE.47)
CXX_MODE.49 := $(CXX_MODE.48)
CXX_MODE.5 := 14
CXX_MODE.6 := $(CXX_MODE.5)
GXX_VERSION := $(shell $(CXX) -dumpversion | awk -F. '$$1<5{print $$1$$2} $$1>=5{print $$1}')
CXX_MODE := $(CXX_MODE.$(GXX_VERSION))
ifneq($(STRICT),)
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++$(CXX_MODE) -pedantic -pedantic-errors
else
CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++$(CXX_MODE)
endif
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this "dot" syntax documented somewhere ? Got a link ?

Comment: I recall that gcc defines a macro that indicates which Cxx revision level it implements. A more evil implementation would run gcc, dump that macro, and use that to pick the right option.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik if you mean `__cplusplus`, that's required by the standard, but wasn't set accurately until GCC 4.7 so you'd get the wrong answer.

Comment: @kebs they're just make variables. The dot is a valid character in a variable name. You could use underscores if you prefer. All I'm doing is concatenating `CXX_MODE.` and `$(GXX_VERSION)` and then referencing the variable of that name, `$(CXX_MODE.$(GXX_VERSION))`, which is one of the variables defined above. The dot is not doing anything special, just a delimiter between the fixed part of the name and the part that comes from expanding another variable, to make it visually distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, as this does not provide an automatic selection, but I thought it could be useful anyway.

You could use a make command-line option to select what you want:

```
ifeq($(CPP11),Y)
    CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11
endif

ifeq($(CPP14),Y)
    CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++14
endif
```

Calling would be done this way:

```
make <target> CPP11=Y
```

or

```
make <target> CPP14=Y
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this topic is quite old now, but I'd like to submit my answer anyway as it might help some people having the same issue.

I made a bash script (named c++_latest_version.sh) which tries every C++ standard from C++23 to C++98, called by the Makefile.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Some error handling of arguments.
echo "int main(){}" > /tmp/c++_version.cpp
if (( $? != 0 )); then
    echo "Cannot create temporary file in /tmp directory." >&2
    exit 2
fi
if [[ "$2" == "NO_WIP_STANDARD" ]]; then
    cpp_versions=(23 20 17 14 11 03 98)
else
    cpp_versions=(23 2b 20 2a 17 1z 14 1y 11 0x 03 98)
fi
for cpp_version in ${cpp_versions[@]}; do
    version_flag="-std=c++$cpp_version"
    "$1" $version_flag /tmp/c++_version.cpp -o /tmp/c++_version.out &> /dev/null
    if (( $? == 0 )); then
        echo "-std=c++$cpp_version"
        exit 0
    fi
done
echo "How in the hell your compiler can't even run c++98 code ?" >&2
exit 3
```

The script is called as `./c++_latest_standard.sh [g++ or clang++] [NO_WIP_STANDARD].

And then the Makefile :

```
# Uncomment this line if encountering compile-related issues with C++2b, C++2a, C++1z, C++1y or C++0x (C++ version is displayed by the Makefile).
# WIP_STANDARD_MODE=NO_WIP_STANDARD

# Comment those two lines if you're using another compiler than g++ and clang++, and don't forget to set yourself the C++ standard you want in CXX_VERSION (or replace it in CXX_FLAGS below).
CXX_VERSION_ERROR   =   $(shell ./c++_latest_version.sh $(CXX) $(WIP_STANDARD_MODE) 2>&1)
CXX_VERSION =   $(shell ./c++_latest_version.sh $(CXX) $(WIP_STANDARD_MODE) 2> /dev/null)

CXXFLAGS  +=  ... $(CXX_VERSION)

# write your compiling stuff here
```

You should have noticed the NO_WIP_STANDARD variable I wrote, it is used to disable "Working In Progress" standards, like c++2b for partially implemented C++23, as it may cause compilation issues.
On my machine (Arch Linux), I had an issue with clang++, compiling OpenGL with C++2b (there was an underlying issue with cmath header, maybe compatibility wasn't properly set).

If one would like me to post the whole bash script, I can do it (not done so far to only post what is strictly necessary.

I also agree every compiler should have a flag to compile with latest standard, without resorting to such inelegant tricks as testing every flag until the latest one is found.
If someone thinks about an improvement, I'm open for your suggestions.
Hope I helped :)